# How do you apply a callback (cufon) to the Galleria jquery plugin when you click on next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, cufon, galleria

I'm using the Galleria jquery plugin. What i would like to be able to do is apply cufon to the caption text / galleria-info-title text but i can't see how. I presume i need to add it as a callback somewhere in the galleria call but i can't see where for the life of me!

If anyone can help i would be eternally grateful!

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [API reference](http://galleria.aino.se/media/galleria/docs/API%20reference/symbols/Galleria.html) there is a method called `bind` that allows you to execute a function when an event is triggered.  Something akin to this:

```
this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function() { Cufon.refresh(); });
```

That should get you started.

**update**
I've never actually used Galleria.  But, what happens when you do this:

```
this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {
    fixCaption(e.imageTarget);
    Cufon.refresh();
});
```

Comment: I've got these 3 functions that look like the code you've shown. But i can't get it to like what you've suggested.

 this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {
            fixCaption(e.imageTarget);
        });

Comment: Hey, would you be able to expand on your answer at all? I cannot get it to work at all!

Answer (score 1):

you can get the nav Dom like this and do what you want:

```
Galleria.ready(function(options) {
  this.$('image-nav-right').click(function(){
    //code
  })
  this.$('image-nav-left').click(function(){
    //code
  })
}
```